# JQuery Ajax won't error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function moveIt(result, finish) {
    $result = $(result);
    $result.find('#main-content-wrapper').appendTo('#aem-content');
    $result.appendTo('#scriptDiv');

    if (finish !== undefined) {
        finish();
    }
}

function isAuthSpace(path) {
    if (path.toLowerCase().indexOf("shop/") > 0) return true;
    return false;
}

function finishInjecting() {
    ProcessInjection("div.dyna-prd-lnk", parseDivTag,   pumpDivTag, "Shop.aspx/GetLinks");
}

function AEMLoadError(isAuth) {
    var fileToLoad = "unAuth.html";
    if (isAuth) {
        fileToLoad = "auth.html";
    }
    $("#aem-content").load(fileToLoad, finishInjecting);
}

function breakAEMLoadPath(path) {
    return BreakTheAEMLoadPath === true ? "2" : path;
}

function PullAEM(path, finish) {
    var isAuth = isAuthSpace(path);
    var ppath = breakAEMLoadPath(path);
    $.ajax({
        url: ppath,
        success: function (result) {
            moveIt(result, finish);
        },
        error: function () {
            AEMLoadError(isAuth);
        },
        dataType: "html"
    });
}
```

When I call the above function PullAEM(path, finish), no matter what value I put in path parameter, the ajax call calls the success function, if the path has garbage in it, say it's empty, the call succeeds (even though it should fail). When it should fail, the result contains the contents of the current page which is not what path is pointing to. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When you debug this in your browser, what is the HTTP request being made by the AJAX call?  I suspect that trying to call an empty URL is resulting in the browser requesting the current relative URL.

Comment: ... and, once you've found that URL (even if it *is* garbage), what response does that URL get when you visit it in a browser? It might be a server-side issue, where should-be-errors are handled "nicely".

Comment: Basically your both right.  I find this enormously strange behavior.  What I found was that if I could type something that would give me an error, like a 400 or 404 in the address bar/window, then that was what I needed in the path argument/parameter.  Thank you bot for showing me the way!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone answering so fast.  I'm not sure what the problem was but after I cleaned it all up to post it up here it worked great!  Though, it ay have been something you both were saying.

This is working perfectly....